# Node.js + Mongodb: is it possible to invoke 'save' on a data returned from a database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.users.findOne({}, function (err, user) {
  //update or add a field
  user.name = 'Phil';
  //is the next line possible?
  user.save(); //error :(
});
```

is there a function like 'save' so that my changes to 'user' will be save in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`save`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#save) method on the collection to do that:

```
db.users.findOne({}, function (err, user) {
  user.name = 'Phil';
  db.users.save(user);
});
```

It performs a full document replacement by `_id`, so using an `update` with `{$set: {name: 'Phil'}}` would be more efficient in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the native driver.

This sort of syntax works fine if you use [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) as a MongoDB driver.